# Trying to find recurrence for simple Dynamic Programming problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this question:

> Therasa is a Nurse. She wants to give some tablets to the patients in
>   her practice. All the patients sit in a line and each of them has a
>   rating score according to his or her health score. Therasa wants to
>   give at least 1 tablet for each patient. Patients get jealous of their
>   immediate neighbors, so if two patients sit next to each other then
>   the one with the higher rating must get more tablets. Therasa wants to
>   save money, so she wants to minimize the total number of tablets.
>
> Input The first line of the input is an integer N, the number of
>   patients in Therasa’s practice. Each of the following N lines contains
>   an integer indicates the health score of each patient.
>
> Output Output a single line containing the minimum number of tablets
>   Therasa must give.
>
> Constraints 1 <= N <= 100000 1 <= health score <= 100000

Could someone give me some intuition for the dp recurrence?

I tried this but it's failing on some test cases

```
n = int(input())
h = []
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    h.append(x)

dp  = [0] * len(h)
dp[0] = 1

for i in range(1, len(h)):
    if h[i] > h[i-1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + 1
    else:
        dp[i] = 1 

for i in range(len(h)-2, -1, -1):
    if h[i]>=h[i+1] and dp[i]<=dp[i+1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i+1]

print(sum(dp))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last part (while traversing in reverse direction), you have a slight mistake:

```
for i in range(len(h)-2, -1, -1):
    if h[i]>=h[i+1] and dp[i]<=dp[i+1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i+1]
```

should be:

```
for i in range(len(h)-2, -1, -1):
    if h[i]>h[i+1] and dp[i]<=dp[i+1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i+1] + 1
```

Problem here is when patient i has greater healtcare but has less (or same) amount of tablets. In the first case, your condition is true but you are not fixing the problem. In the second case, you are making sure patient i has more tables.

Irrelevant from getting correct answer, another improvement I would suggest is replacing these:

```
dp  = [0] * len(h)
dp[0] = 1

for i in range(1, len(h)):
    if h[i] > h[i-1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + 1
    else:
        dp[i] = 1
```

With these:

```
dp  = [1] * len(h)

for i in range(1, len(h)):
    if h[i] > h[i-1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + 1
```

Because we know that each patient is going to get **at least** 1 tablet.

**Update:** Here is an example case where your first code will fail:
h = [10, 10, 1]
Your code will calculate dp=[1, 1, 1]